# execute sub command within xargs

Tags: shell, unix

I want to make soft link of all the binary files of folder A to folder B
like,

```
find /home/A/bin/* -print | xargs -I {} ln -sf {} /tmp/B/$(basename {})
```

the problem is that I cant execute sub command inside the xargs.

what should I do ?

Answer (score 12):

launching a subshell will do what you want:

```
find /home/A/bin/* -print |
xargs -I {} sh -c 'ln -sf "$1" /tmp/B/$(basename "$1")' - {}
```

Comment: This is the real answer to the question.  @alinsoar may have showed a better way to do what the OP wanted to do, but this is how you do what he asked for.

Comment: Do any of the `$`s need to be escaped?

Comment: No, because they all appear within single quotes. They will not be expanded until `sh` is executing it.

Answer (score 5):

```
mkdir A ; touch A/file1 ; touch A/file2
mkdir B
for i in `ls A`; do ln -sf $PWD/A/$i B/; done
```

Answer (score 3):

You can execute directly `ln -sf /h/a/bin/* /tmp` .

Or, you can go to /tmp, and do so:

```
cd /tmp
ln -sf /home/A/bin/*
```

Using xargs:

```
cd /tmp
find /home/A/bin/* -print0 | xargs -0 ln
```

Comment: thnx for the answer. That worked like a charm. but how can i execute any sub command inside the xargs ??